# How to show user error message through JasperReports Scriptlet?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

In JasperReport I have implemented validation logic of the input control parameters. Now the problem is that when I throw a JRScriptletException from my code then I can see the error stack trace on JasperReports Server page. Now this is what I think is weird. JasperReport should have done the job of changing an error stack trace to a nice Dialog box which gives some meaningful message. Why would the end user be interested to see the error trace?

But coming to my question here, now I want to achieve that the JasperReport server page should show a dialog box with a meaningful error message. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: @mdahlman I see you one of the top answerer in this section. Could you give me some hints here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw `JSShowOnlyErrorMessage` instead of `JRScriptletException`. It is part of JasperReport Server library jar.

I am quite disappointed from Jasper in terms of documentation here but finally my colleague managed to find this one. It is quite frustrating if one needs to spend so much amount of time to dig in the code to find such kind of information.